# is it possible to combine 3 same value in different array into one?

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have a couple of arrays contains values just like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [NAMA_MDS] => AGUNG RUDIYANTO               
        [Call] => 182
        [RO] => 151
        [NAMA_SGRUP] => Kanzler Singles               
        [EC] => 247
        [OT] => 57
        [Ratio] => 4
        [SBQ] => 6586
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [NAMA_MDS] => AGUNG RUDIYANTO               
        [Call] => 182
        [RO] => 151
        [NAMA_SGRUP] => Yogurt Squeeze 120 GR         
        [EC] => 271
        [OT] => 103
        [Ratio] => 2
        [SBQ] => 9449
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [NAMA_MDS] => AGUNG RUDIYANTO               
        [Call] => 182
        [RO] => 151
        [NAMA_SGRUP] => Yoghurt Drink 250 ML          
        [EC] => 271
        [OT] => 106
        [Ratio] => 2
        [SBQ] => 4960
    )
```

and because of that,  when I foreach the data to my table the result gives me like this :

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Nama Sales</th>
                <th rowspan="2" width="20%">Nama Barang</th>
                <th colspan="2">EC</th>
                <th colspan="2">OT</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Ratio</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Sales QTY</th>
                <th colspan="2">Drop Size</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <!-- <th width="100%">Nama Barang</th> -->
                <th>total</th><th width="10%">% vs Call</th>
                <th>total</th><th width="10%">% vs Call</th>
<!--                 <th>Ratio</th>
                <th>Sales QTY</th> -->
                <th>Per-EC</th><th>Per-OT</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>AGUNG RUDIYANTO</td>
                <td><small>Kanzler Singles</small></td>
                <td>247</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>57</td>
                <td>38%</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>6,586</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>116</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>AGUNG RUDIYANTO</td>
                <td><small>Yogurt Squeeze 120 GR</small></td>
                <td>271</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>103</td>
                <td>69%</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>9,449</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>92</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>AGUNG RUDIYANTO</td>
                <td><small>Yoghurt Drink 250 ML</small></td>
                <td>271</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>106</td>
                <td>71%</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4,960</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>47</td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
           </div>
```

and what I want to achieve is to have table like this :

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive" style="overflow: scroll;height: 500px;">
          <table class="table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Nama Sales</th>
                <th rowspan="2" width="20%">Nama Barang</th>
                <th colspan="2">EC</th>
                <th colspan="2">OT</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Ratio</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Sales QTY</th>
                <th colspan="2">Drop Size</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <!-- <th width="100%">Nama Barang</th> -->
                <th>total</th><th width="10%">% vs Call</th>
                <th>total</th><th width="10%">% vs Call</th>
<!--                 <th>Ratio</th>
                <th>Sales QTY</th> -->
                <th>Per-EC</th><th>Per-OT</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">AGUNG RUDIYANTO</td>
                <td><small>Kanzler Singles</small></td>
                <td>247</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>57</td>
                <td>38%</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>6,586</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>116</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><small>Yogurt Squeeze 120 GR</small></td>
                <td>271</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>103</td>
                <td>69%</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>9,449</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>92</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><small>Yoghurt Drink 250 ML</small></td>
                <td>271</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>106</td>
                <td>71%</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>4,960</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>47</td>
              </tr>
```

and I guess and correct me if I'm wrong, I have to make the arrays looks like this to achieve the table that I want  :

```
Array
(
[NAMA_MDS] => AGUNG RUDIYANTO =>
   [0] => Array
    (              
        [Call] => 182
        [RO] => 151
        [NAMA_SGRUP] => Kanzler Singles               
        [EC] => 247
        [OT] => 57
        [Ratio] => 4
        [SBQ] => 6586
    )

[1] => Array
    (             
        [Call] => 182
        [RO] => 151
        [NAMA_SGRUP] => Yogurt Squeeze 120 GR         
        [EC] => 271
        [OT] => 103
        [Ratio] => 2
        [SBQ] => 9449
    )

[2] => Array
    (          
        [Call] => 182
        [RO] => 151
        [NAMA_SGRUP] => Yoghurt Drink 250 ML          
        [EC] => 271
        [OT] => 106
        [Ratio] => 2
        [SBQ] => 4960
    )
```

or something similar but i have no idea how to achieve the table that i want.
can someone tell me how i can have that table that im try to achieve it with changing the array shape or without changing the arrays shape ?

here is my Controller:

```
public function test(){
    $data['db_default'] =  $this->db_default->default();
    $data['report2'] = $this->m_report->table2($data['db_default'][0]['databasename']);
    $data['content'] = 'tempelates/BKL/Report_B';
    $this->load->view('Tempelate',$data);
}
```

and this is my code in my view:

```
            <tbody>
          <?php foreach($report2->result_array() as $row){
            $Call = $row['Call'];
            $vsc = ceil(($row['EC']*100)/$Call);
            $RO = $row['RO'];
            $vsr = ceil(($row['OT']*100)/$RO)?>
          <tr>
            <td><?=$row['NAMA_MDS']?></td>
            <td><small><?=$row['NAMA_SGRUP']?></small></td>
            <td><?=$row['EC']?></td>
            <td><?php if($vsc >= 100){echo '100%';}else{echo $vsc.'%';}?></td>
            <td><?=$row['OT']?></td>
            <td><?php if($vsr >= 100){echo '100%';}else{echo $vsr.'%';}?></td>
            <td><?=$row['Ratio']?></td>
            <td><?=number_format($row['SBQ'])?></td>
            <td><?=ceil($row['SBQ']/$row['EC'])?></td>
            <td><?=ceil($row['SBQ']/$row['OT'])?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php }?>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$report = 
array(

   array
    (   'NAMA_MDS' =>' AGUNG RUDIYANTO' ,           
        'Call' => 182,
        'RO' => 151,
        'NAMA_SGRUP' =>   'kkkk'  ,           
        'EC' => 247,
        'OT' => 57,
        'Ratio' => 4,
        'SBQ' => 6586,
    ),
   array
    (   'NAMA_MDS' =>' AGUNG RUDIYANTO' ,           
        'Call' => 182,
        'RO' => 151,
        'NAMA_SGRUP' =>   'kkkk'  ,           
        'EC' => 247,
        'OT' => 57,
        'Ratio' => 4,
        'SBQ' => 6586,
    ),
    );

$html = '';//here
?>
<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Nama Sales</th>
                <th rowspan="2" width="20%">Nama Barang</th>
                <th colspan="2">EC</th>
                <th colspan="2">OT</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Ratio</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Sales QTY</th>
                <th colspan="2">Drop Size</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <!-- <th width="100%">Nama Barang</th> -->
                <th>total</th><th width="10%">% vs Call</th>
                <th>total</th><th width="10%">% vs Call</th>
<!--                 <th>Ratio</th>
                <th>Sales QTY</th> -->
                <th>Per-EC</th><th>Per-OT</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          
 <tbody>
          <?php foreach($report as $row){
            $Call = $row['Call'];
            $vsc = ceil(($row['EC']*100)/$Call);
            $RO = $row['RO'];
            $vsr = ceil(($row['OT']*100)/$RO);
          
?>
          <tr>
<?php if($html != $row['NAMA_MDS']){?>//and here
            <td rowspan="3"><?=$row['NAMA_MDS']?></td>
<?php }
$html = $row['NAMA_MDS'];?>

            <td><small><?=$row['NAMA_SGRUP']?></small></td>
            <td><?=$row['EC']?></td>
            <td><?php if($vsc >= 100){echo '100%';}else{echo $vsc.'%';}?></td>
            <td><?=$row['OT']?></td>
            <td><?php if($vsr >= 100){echo '100%';}else{echo $vsr.'%';}?></td>
            <td><?=$row['Ratio']?></td>
            <td><?=number_format($row['SBQ'])?></td>
            <td><?=ceil($row['SBQ']/$row['EC'])?></td>
            <td><?=ceil($row['SBQ']/$row['OT'])?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php }?>
       </tbody>
```

if you want to make row span count dynamic use the last array you listed with count of index and same way

Comment: if u dont mind can u give some example of counting of index for dynamic rowspan in my case .. and i'll be thankful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$report =array(

'AGUNG RUDIYANTO'=>array(
    array('NAMA_MDS' =>'AGUNG RUDIYANTO' ,           
        'Call' => 182,
        'RO' => 151,
        'NAMA_SGRUP' =>   'kkkk'  ,           
        'EC' => 247,
        'OT' => 57,
        'Ratio' => 4,
        'SBQ' => 6586,
    ),
   array
    (   'NAMA_MDS' =>' AGUNG RUDIYANTO' ,           
        'Call' => 182,
        'RO' => 151,
        'NAMA_SGRUP' =>   'kkkk'  ,           
        'EC' => 247,
        'OT' => 57,
        'Ratio' => 4,
        'SBQ' => 6586,
    ),
     array
    (   'NAMA_MDS' =>' AGUNG RUDIYANTO' ,           
        'Call' => 182,
        'RO' => 151,
        'NAMA_SGRUP' =>   'kkkk'  ,           
        'EC' => 247,
        'OT' => 57,
        'Ratio' => 4,
        'SBQ' => 6586,
    ),),
    'AGUNG ssRUDIYANTO'=>array(
    array('NAMA_MDS' =>'AGUNG RUDIYANTO' ,           
        'Call' => 182,
        'RO' => 151,
        'NAMA_SGRUP' =>   'kkkk'  ,           
        'EC' => 247,
        'OT' => 57,
        'Ratio' => 4,
        'SBQ' => 6586,
    ),
   array
    (   'NAMA_MDS' =>' AGUNG RUDIYANTO' ,           
        'Call' => 182,
        'RO' => 151,
        'NAMA_SGRUP' =>   'kkkk'  ,           
        'EC' => 247,
        'OT' => 57,
        'Ratio' => 4,
        'SBQ' => 6586,
    ),
     array
    (   'NAMA_MDS' =>' AGUNG RUDIYANTO' ,           
        'Call' => 182,
        'RO' => 151,
        'NAMA_SGRUP' =>   'kkkk'  ,           
        'EC' => 247,
        'OT' => 57,
        'Ratio' => 4,
        'SBQ' => 6586,
    ),),
    
    );
    
    
?>
<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Nama Sales</th>
                <th rowspan="2" width="20%">Nama Barang</th>
                <th colspan="2">EC</th>
                <th colspan="2">OT</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Ratio</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Sales QTY</th>
                <th colspan="2">Drop Size</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <!-- <th width="100%">Nama Barang</th> -->
                <th>total</th><th width="10%">% vs Call</th>
                <th>total</th><th width="10%">% vs Call</th>
<!--                 <th>Ratio</th>
                <th>Sales QTY</th> -->
                <th>Per-EC</th><th>Per-OT</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          
 <tbody>
          <?php
          $html = '';
          foreach($report as $key => $row1){?>
            <?php foreach($row1 as $row){
             $Call = $row['Call'];
            $vsc = ceil(($row['EC']*100)/$Call);
            $RO = $row['RO'];
            $vsr = ceil(($row['OT']*100)/$RO);
          
?>
     <tr>
        <?php if($key != $html){
        ?>
            <td rowspan="<?php echo count($report[$key]); ?>">
                <?php echo $key ?></td>
            <?php }
            $html =$key;
            ?>
             
       <td><small><?=$row['NAMA_SGRUP']?></small></td>
            <td><?=$row['EC']?></td>
            <td><?php if($vsc >= 100){echo '100%';}else{echo $vsc.'%';}?></td>
            <td><?=$row['OT']?></td>
            <td><?php if($vsr >= 100){echo '100%';}else{echo $vsr.'%';}?></td>
            <td><?=$row['Ratio']?></td>
            <td><?=number_format($row['SBQ'])?></td>
            <td><?=ceil($row['SBQ']/$row['EC'])?></td>
            <td><?=ceil($row['SBQ']/$row['OT'])?></td>
                       </tr>
            <?php }?>
        <?php }?>
       </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnaks again for ur reply habibi .. but i dont understand i just tried to followed ur logic  and it gives a messy table with error 
`Cannot use object of type CI_DB_sqlsrv_result as array`
because im using result_array . but the errors comes from this line :
<td rowspan="<?php echo count($report[$key]); ?>"><?php echo $key ?></td>
. sorry for bothering u by asking too much :)

Comment: result_array() ; first loop throw your array in controller and make it like the array that i use it ; or change your select or send me the query that you use